# MultipleApiVersions with Swagger

Tags: swagger

I am trying to enable versioning on a REST API, where the version is specified in the header, as `"api-version":2`, vendor media type, as `"accept: application/vnd.company.resource-v2+json`, `application/json; version=2"`, or in a query string `"?version=2"`.  The implementation is using IHttpRouteConstraint and RouteFactoryAttribute.  This works perfectly.  However, Swagger is not able match the right model with the correct versioned document.  The operationId is always from the version 1 model.

```
public class DevicesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, RouteVersion( "api/devices", 1, Name = "v1.devices" )]
    [ResponseType( typeof( IEnumerable<Models.V1.Device> ) )]
    public IHttpActionResult GetV1( )
    {
        return Ok( new List<Models.V1.Device> { ... } );
    }

    [HttpGet, RouteVersion( "api/devices", 2, Name = "v2.devices" )]
    [ResponseType( typeof( IEnumerable<Models.V2.Device> ) )]
    public IHttpActionResult GetV2( )
    {
        return Ok( new List<Models.V2.Device> { ... } );
    }
}
```

Swagger docs for V2 has the wrong operationId and MIME Types.

```
"tags":
[
    "Devices"
],
"summary": "Get a list of device(s) by the device identifier",
"operationId": "Devices_GetV1",
"consumes": [ ],
"produces": 
[
    "application/vnd.safe.inventory-v1+json",
    "application/json",
    "text/json",
    "application/vnd.safe.inventory-v1+xml",
    "application/xml",
    "text/xml"
],
...
```

**Swashbuckle 5.2.2**

I have tried customizing the ApiExplorer as descripted in these post:

```
github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/558
github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/317
```

I have also tried building a custom selector.

I also went down this route as well, but I don’t think that is the same issue.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-swashbuckle-customize/

Asking for any direction any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try add `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning.ApiExplorer` and use `apiExplorer` as explained here: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Documentation
This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out a solution with a custom ApiExplorer as described in http://blog.ulriksen.net/versioned-iapiexplorer

In the Swagger configuration: using MultipleApiVersions

```
c.MultipleApiVersions( ( apiDesc, version ) =>
{
    var versionConstraint = apiDesc.Route.Constraints[ "version" ] as RouteVersionConstraint;
    return ( versionConstraint != null ) && versionConstraint.AllowedVersion == version.ConvertTo<int>( );
},
vc =>
{
    vc.Version( "2", "API V2" ); //add this line when v2 is released
    vc.Version( "1", "API V1" );
} );
```

Comment: Hi There, what is your class for RouteVersionContraint?