# Using Swagger/Swashbuckle with a namespace versioned ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have an ASP.NET Web API app that I have versioned using namespace versioning.

For example, this method is accessible at ***api/v1/Location/Process***:

```
namespace Project.Controllers.V1
{
  public class LocationController : BaseController
  {
    [HttpsRequired, HttpGet]
    public async Task<ApiResponse> Process(string sessionToken, string id)
```

Swagger is set up to deal with this setup using the MultipleApiVersions method:

```
c.MultipleApiVersions((apiDesc, version) => {
         var path = apiDesc.RelativePath.Split('/');
         var pathVersion = path[1];

        return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(pathVersion, version, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0;
     },
     vc => {
          vc.Version("v1", "Foundbite Client API V1");
     });
```

However when the Swagger UI is generated the methods have the full namespace and controller name in the url: ***api/V1.Location/Process***

Anyone know how I can edit the paths Swagger will use so I can create the correct url? (Basically just need to replace that fullstop). I ideally don't want to use routing attributes.

(There is a similar question to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387353/using-swagger-with-a-namespaced-versionned-webapi) but it misses some keen points that I'd like to address.)

Comment: I think the easiest is to use a [routeprefix("v1")] for your controllers, although i know you said you'd rather not

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34863439/1841212 does it solve your problem?

Comment: @James Mundy how did you resolve this finally?

Comment: @Moumit I'm sorry but afraid I can't entirely remember. I think it was using the route prefix mentioned above